# Verwendung vom Imperfekt in der gesprochenen Sprache

Tags: preterite

Ich weiß, dass es drauf ankommt, wo man in Deutschland ist, aber welche Verben benutzt man am häufigsten in der gesprochenen Sprache? Fast überall werden *sein* und *haben* meistens im Imperfekt statt dem Perfekt verwendet, und das heißt nämlich im Hochdeutschen – ich weiß nicht ob das für die Mundarten gilt. Aber schon im Süden hört man das Perfekt öfter als das Imperfekt.

Hier eine Liste der Verben, die im Alltag im Imperfekt benutzt werden und mir heute eingefallen sind ~

- Diese sind Verben, deren Funktion oft als Kopula bezeichnet wird

  - *sein*
  - *heißen*
  - *werden*
  - *aussehen*
- Diese Verben haben eine imperfekte Bedeutung => vgl. "(sich/etw. hin)setzen, legen, und stellen"

  - *sitzen*
  - *liegen*
  - *stehen*
- Die folgenden Verben sind normalerweise bei den Konstruktionen benutzt, die einen Nebensatz als Prädikat haben (z. B. "Ich dachte, dass du kommen wolltest")

  - *denken*
  - *wissen*
  - *glauben*
  - *sagen*
  - *meinen*
- Und dann die Modalverben (ein ähnlicher Fall wie beim obenstehenden Verben, man hat hier meistens keinen Nebensatz, sondern einfach nur den Rest des Prädikats)

  - *müssen*
  - *können*
  - *dürfen*
  - *sollen*
  - *wollen*
- Und diese einfach extrem oft benutzt – beim Verbum *haben* ist nur den Ausdruck des Besitzens gemeint. Ich habe eine starke Vermutung, dass hierzu noch viele mehr gehören.

  - *haben*
  - *geben* – nur beim Ausdruck "es gab"

Also nun meine Frage: Fehlen hier irgendwelche Verben? Kann man noch weitere dazu nehmen?

Comment: Diese Frage, da es keine eindeutige Antwort gibt, ist eher für ein Diskussionforum geeignet als für SE (da SE eine Frage+Antwort Plattform ist ;) )

Comment: Danke, da hast du bestimmt recht. Sollte ich dann die Frage löschen?

Comment: Ich denke schon, dass man eine relative genaue Antwort geben kann. Wobei man sich dann hier wohl am besten auf "Contemporary German in Northern Germany" beschränken sollte. Hier noch einige weitere Verben: färben, erweisen, scheinen, bleiben, wirken, dünken

Comment: @Em1 Ja, das sind Verben. Sollen sie etwas gemein haben? ;) Ich denke, wer Wörter wie „dünken“ überhaupt benutzt, benutzt vielleicht allgemein das Imperfekt häufiger als andere.

Comment: Siehe auch: http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/prateritum-imperfekt-perfekt.php

Comment: Noch ne Anmerkung: Es kann auch entscheidend sein, ob es ein Frage- oder Aussagesatz ist. Dort, wo ich lebe, gibt es so ein ausgeglichenes Maß zwischen beiden Verwendung. Dadurch hört man diese Varianten: "Bist du in Urlaub gewesen? - Ja, ich war in Urlaub." oder "Hast du einen schönen Tag gehabt? - Ja, ich hatte einen schönen Tag."

Comment: Glauben und kennen sind auch Verben, deren Funktion oft als Kopula bezeichnet wird:

> "Ich glaube Tom."

> "Ich kenne Tom."

Comment: @Felix Falsch. Tom ist in beiden Fällen ein Objekt. **Wen** kenne ich und **wem** glaube ich.

Comment: @Em1: Klar, stimmt -.-

Comment: Eine Anmerkung: In den hoch- und höchstalemannischen Dialekten gibt es kein Präteritum. Es wird daher häufig auch in der Hochsprache nicht oder nicht richtig verwendet.

Comment: Vielleicht solltest du deine Frage umwandeln in: Welche Gruppen von Verben benutzt man eher im Imperfekt als im Perfekt und dann deine (relativ vollständig scheinende) Liste als Antwort posten mit der Bitte, eventuelle Ergänzungen einzueditieren (z.B. weitere Verben oder welche dieser Verben in bestimmten Regionen auch auf dieser Liste zu finden wären, könnte man ja durch Kürzel machen, bspw B für Bayern oder so). Wenn du Glück hast, kriegst du sogar den Self-Learner-Badge dafür :) Oder wenn du viele Edits erwartest, könntest du die Antwort auch zum Community-Wiki machen.

Answer (score 3):

deine Frage wird von meinen Studenten häufig gestellt. Eine allumfassende Antwort würde einiger Forschung bedürfen und der ausführliche Artikel unter http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/prateritum-imperfekt-perfekt.php ist, fürchte ich, für den Laien in der Praxis leider kaum anwendbar.

Hier meine Ergänzung und Korrektur deiner Liste als erste **Daumenregel**:

**A. Folgende Verben stehen gerne im Präteritum:**

**1. Die Hilfsverben:**

- haben
- sein
- werden

**2. Die Modalverben:**

- können
- dürfen
- müssen
- sollen
- wollen
- möchten

**3. Positionsverben:**

- stehen
- liegen
- sitzen
- hängen
- stecken

**4. Verben des "geistigen" Zustands bzw. der Vorstellung**

- denken
- wissen
- glauben (, dass ...)
- meinen (im Sinne von sagen wollen)

**5. Weitere Zustands-, Eigenschafts- bzw. "Besitzstands-"Verben**

- heißen
- aussehen
- besitzen
- geben (es gab)
  ...

---

**B. Ausnahmen und Korrekturen**

Verben, die in der gesprochenen Sprache eher im Perfekt verwendet werden:

1. Ausnahme bei Zustandsverben

   - bleiben
2. Korrektur der Liste

   - sagen

Comment: Die Frage ist wirklich nicht leicht. Schön, dass es jetzt endlich mal jemand versucht hat. Deine Liste ist jedoch leider genau so 'unvollständig', wie die vom OP. Ich hatte in einem Kommentar schon einige Wörter ergänzt, die je nach Kontext auch im Präteritum stehen. Nehmen wir ein Beispiel heraus: *scheinen*. Schonmal gesagt: "Es hat geschienen, dass..."? Oder vergleich mal *erweisen*: "Es hat sich erwiesen" hat zwar ein paar hundert tausend Google Hits, aber immer noch signifikant weniger als "Es schien". Und *sagte* ich schon, dass imho bleiben und sagen auch oft im Prät. stehen.